# Making tab Active/Inactive is not showing the proper data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tabs

First,
I have three tabs which were showing the proper and actual data as per my requirement, but the issue was the tab's were not getting active properly.

When I used to click `second` tab. It was showing the data properly but the active was getting moved to `first` tab. The `active/inacive` was done by the javascript. here is the code for the JS:-

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs1').each(function () {
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
            $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content = $($active[0].hash);
            $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $(this.hash).hide();
            });
            $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();
                $active = $(this);
                $content = $(this.hash);
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();
            });
        });
    });
```

But when I changed the JS code from the above js to like below js my active was working perfectly but the data was not coming as per my requirement. See the JS Code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs1').each(function () {
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
            $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content = $($active[0].hash);
            $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $(this.hash).hide();
            });
            $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();
                $active = $(e.target);
                $content = $(e.target.hash);
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();
            });
        });
    });
```

Also see the server code and html for the same

```
<ul class='tabs1'>
            <li><a href='#tab1' id="allNews" runat="server" onserverclick="allNews_ServerClick">All News</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab2' id="forNgo" runat="server" onserverclick="forNgo_ServerClick">For NGO</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab3' id="fromNgo" runat="server" onserverclick="fromNgo_ServerClick">From NGO</a></li>
        </ul>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void ddlSortOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            //string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost) = " + ddlYear.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost " + ddlSortOrder.SelectedValue;
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost) = " + ddlYear.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost " + ddlSortOrder.SelectedValue;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void allNews_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set user type accordingly in all below methods
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.userId = dbo.tbl_User.Id where usertype != '2'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
          //  allNews.Attributes["class"] = "active";
        }
    }
    protected void forNgo_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.userId = dbo.tbl_User.Id where usertype != '2'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
           // forNgo.Attributes["class"] = "active";
        }
    }
    protected void fromNgo_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM  dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.userId = dbo.tbl_User.Id where usertype = '2'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
           // fromNgo.Attributes["class"] = "active";
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE LISTVIEW CODE**:-

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstNews" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lstNews_PagePropertiesChanging">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="Newsdiv">
                            <p class="Newspara"><a id="a1" runat="server" href='<%# string.Format("#{0}", Eval("Id")) %>' class="modal-popup"><%# Eval("title") %></a></p>
                            <p class="NewsDate">
                                News Posted:
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt}", Eval("dateforPost")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label"><%# Eval("ngo_name") %></span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="NewsDate1"><a href='<%# Eval("title") %>'>Click here</a> to know more </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id='<%# Eval("Id") %>' class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-container">
                                <div class="popup-content">
                                    <div class="popup-close js-popup-close modal-close">X</div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="popup-para"><%# Eval("title") %></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="padding: 7px;">
                                        <p class="NewsDate">
                                            News Posted:                                   
                                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt}", Eval("dateforPost")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="SStorypara">
                                            <%# Eval("description") %>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                <div class="pagination">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="dpNews" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstNews" PageSize="3">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current-page" />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
```

Comment: you can better use this plugin for tabs http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: I guess there is some issue with codebehind. I wont be able to change all the logic now as I m on my deadline to complete this.

Comment: are you using three different list on the each tab?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: What do you mean by `list` ?? I have given the HTML in the question.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: It is a `ListView` control from where my data is coming from the database. whose data are divided into the `three` tabs

Comment: ok, so you want three tabs with 3 different listview control that showing different data, When you click on each tab the corresponding list view to be showed to the user? am i right ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: No, I want to show all the three data in only ONE `ListView Control`

Comment: ok, for faster output you can use three different list view to show different data in each tab by using the above mentioned plugin. what's your opinion?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: I am happy with that, but I need the output proper. Can you give the code for three listview. I can show you the code which I used for One listview

Comment: yes sure i will post the html in answer section.

Comment: OK, see the listview code. I will update my questio, Also let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below styles and jquery plugins.

You can put three listviews on each tab content (div element) with tabs-1,tabs-2 and tabs-3

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#allNews">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#forNgo">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fromNgo">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="allNews">
        <asp:ListView ID="lstNews" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lstNews_PagePropertiesChanging">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="Newsdiv">
                        <p class="Newspara"><a id="a1" runat="server" href='<%# string.Format("#{0}", Eval("Id")) %>' class="modal-popup"><%# Eval("title") %></a></p>
                        <p class="NewsDate">
                            News Posted:
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt}", Eval("dateforPost")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label"><%# Eval("ngo_name") %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="NewsDate1"><a href='<%# Eval("title") %>'>Click here</a> to know more </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='<%# Eval("Id") %>' class="popup">
                        <div class="popup-container">
                            <div class="popup-content">
                                <div class="popup-close js-popup-close modal-close">X</div>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="popup-para"><%# Eval("title") %></p>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding: 7px;">
                                    <p class="NewsDate">
                                        News Posted:                                   
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt}", Eval("dateforPost")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="SStorypara">
                                        <%# Eval("description") %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            <div class="pagination">
                <asp:DataPager ID="dpNews" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstNews" PageSize="3">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                            ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current-page" />
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
    </div>
    <div id="forNgo">

    </div>
    <div id="fromNgo">

    </div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dude, can you put the first tab listview code and show me, So that I can implement it for all

Comment: Like the same put the same ListView code on the other div with id forNgo and fromNgo and give different ID than listNews. and then set the different source for each listview control from the server side as you did.

Comment: Ok, let me implement and check

Comment: If you have any problem with the jquery Tabs you can use the ASP.NET tabs control also like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13165/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Tab-Control-Using-the-MultiView-c

Comment: It works for me dude, I can't imagine. Sorry for delay :) If there is any other simpler way please tell me. Whenever I get time i will implement that..!!

Comment: you can use the ASP.NET tabs control for the same. So you can do it without jquery.Only one thing is needed that is styling it.